# Creating a reference to a returned pointer

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I have a node class which inherits from NodeInterface with two functions NodeInterface * return(Left/Right)Child(). This for a class, and we are required to follow this NodeInterface.

I am trying to make an add() function for my BST, and need to pass my current node to the recursive add function as a reference.

```
bool add(T data) {
    return addNodeToNode(data, root);
};

bool addNodeToNode(T data, NodeInterface<T>*& cNode) {
    if ((cNode) == nullptr || cNode == NULL) {
        (cNode) = new Node<T>(data);
        return true;
    }

    int nodeData = (cNode)->getData();
    if (data == (cNode)->getData()) return false;
    if (data < nodeData) {
        addNodeToNode(data, cNode->getLeftChild());
    }
    if (data > nodeData) {
        addNodeToNode(data, cNode->getRightChild());
    }
    return true;
};
```

But I keep getting an error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'NodeInterface *' to 'NodeInterface *&' when I call `addNodeToNode(data, cNode->getLeftChild());` or `addNodeToNode(data, cNode->getRightChild());`

That is super confusing to me, because root is a pointer to a NodeInterface object, and the add(T data) function has no problem calling addNodeToNode with the second parameter being root...

Comment: Why these parens: `(cNode)`?

Comment: aka current Node... since I am working with a tree, c just means current to me

Comment: I asked about the parens - i.e brackets.

Comment: Also the repeated test in the following line is pointless, if the first is true the second will always be true as well: if ((cNode) == nullptr || cNode == NULL)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass a non-const lvalue reference to a temporary (the return value from the function calls) which is not legal. One solution would be to create addNodeToNode overloads that take r-value references, another would be to make your getLeftChild/getRightChild return reference-to-pointer instead of just pointers (that way you would have a reference to the actual pointer stored in the node object).

Honestly, however, trying to have cNode serve the dual role of an input node object and outputting a newly created node strikes me as a very poor design. If you made cNode input-only (and therefore dropped the requirement that it be a reference) and made addNodeToNode's return value the new node object implementing your BST would be far easier.

Comment: "to create addNodeToNode overloads that take r-value references" this should compile but make not much sense otherwise.

Comment: How do you know what getLeft/RightChild returns? What if it returns reference to a pointer?